# Short story about a man trying to travel to the edge of his city by train but the city is endless

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this short story a man tries to find the end of his city by sitting on a train (possibly a sleeper train) until it reaches the country. The train is underground and he checks property values every so often by leaving the train. The values reduce as he gets further from the city centre but eventually start increasing and he realises that the whole planet is one urban sprawl. He admits to having been on the train for a long time to some authority figure and is viewed as a disruptive person as a result. Can anyone tell me the title and/or author?

Comment: Hi there. That's some good info already, but perhaps you could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, any recollection of what magazine you may have read that in, and most importantly, when it would have been published?

Comment: Might it be [this story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192511/5930)?

Comment: @HarryJohnston that should be an answer!

Comment: @Harry Johnston  Yes, I remember a J.G. Ballard story like that.

Comment: "The concentration city" is definitely what I was thinking of. Thanks to everybody to replied.

Comment: @Keith1879 thanks for confirming Harry's identification. I've marked it as a duplicate of the previous question.