# Short story about what seems like an infinite "city;" the protagonist travels forward until he arrives back at the start

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the mid-60's, if I recall correctly, I read a short story in a collection, but I can't remember the title of either the story or the collection (nor the author).

The setting seemed to be a world(?) which to all appearances had no end. The main character became curious about this (I think there was some kind of alphanumeric identification of specific areas or blocks within the "city") and boarded the transport system to ascertain its extent.

The journey went on for days, and he eventually finished up back where he started without having covered any of the trip twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "The Concentration City", also known as "Build-Up", by JG Ballard. which was previously the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192509/seeking-a-story-about-a-subway-train-journey-through-a-universe-made-entirely-o/192511#192511).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Concentration_City):

> "The Concentration City" is set in a "city" encompassing everything in known existence to its inhabitants. The districts comprise endless streets and buildings and seemingly infinitely high and low levels, or floors, with few trees and little wildlife. Cubic space is in shortage and expensive. High speed transportation is in use, but it is implied that many people do not find the need to leave their particular area. The people do not know what lies beyond the endless urban expansion, but seem to care little, and generally assume that there are just endless levels and districts that have existed forever.
>
> The short story follows a physics student named Franz, who devotes his time to the concept of "free space"—the idea that somewhere there must be just infinite amounts of space, a concept labelled as nonsensical by most of the other inhabitants of the city. He also wishes to develop a machine for flight—a relatively unknown theory due to the complete lack of partially open spaces.
>
> Eventually Franz decides to travel on one of the high-speed rail coaches for as long as possible in one direction in order to discover what lies beyond the urban zoning and trying to find free space. The story ends when Franz, after ten days of travelling, realizes that the coach is travelling back in the opposite direction. When he is finally stopped by the authorities he notices the date of a calendar is unchanged from when he set forth travelling. Franz discovers that if one keeps travelling forward, one finally ends back in the same place at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. That's exactly the one. I read it as Build-up in Connoisseur's Science Fiction
by Tom Boardman. I probably should have surmised JG Ballard as the author: very much his kind of story.

Comment: @Mike You can accept by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: It's not really worth me posting a fresh question, I'm just wondering if it's the same story I was thinking about. A 
minor part of the plot in the "endless city" story I was thinking about involves firebugs,  anyone who accidentally causes a fire is known as a firebug and are summarily executed by the firefighters - an apartment caught fire and a smoke dazed couple stagger out, passers by grab them and hold them until the fire crew put out the blaze - then the firemen stand them against a wall and shoot them for being careless and endangering public safety. Same story?